# Eclipse - allowDeadlock runtime option

Tags: java, eclipse, deadlock

`allowDeadlock` is one of Eclipse [runtime-options](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html), but it has no description

> -allowDeadlock  < description>

[Eclipse Code](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/Workbench.java#L2752-L2772) is not executing `UISynchronizer` in that case:

> ```
> if (avoidDeadlock) {
>         UILockListener uiLockListener = new UILockListener(display);
>         Job.getJobManager().setLockListener(uiLockListener);
>         synchronizer = new UISynchronizer(display, uiLockListener);
>         display.setSynchronizer(synchronizer);
>         // declare the main thread to be a startup thread.
>         UISynchronizer.startupThread.set(Boolean.TRUE);
>     } else
>         synchronizer = null;
> ```

But I didn't find any [reference](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=95660) how/when to use it

> I haven't removed the command line argument "-allowDeadlock" - who knows,
>   someone might rely on it. (?)

Is there a use case for using this flag? is it useful for finding dead locks in application that can stuck eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Javadoc of `UILockListener`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/Eclipse%20UI/org/eclipse/ui/internal/UILockListener.java#L27-L28):

> The UI lock listener is used to prevent the UI thread from deadlocking
>   on a lock when the thread owning the lock is attempting to `syncExec`.

If I understand it correctly, `-allowDeadlock` prevents the UI from freezing when a plug-in in the UI thread holds a lock and calls `syncExec` (which it shouldn't). So it's a workaround to use/run third-party plug-ins that do that.

The missing description is tracked in [Eclipse bug 496422](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496422).